# How often does Firebase phone authentication require verification?

Tags: firebase-authentication, price, twitter-digits

as of May 17, digits.com released a statement:

http://get.digits.com/blog/introducing-firebase-phone-authentication

Stating that digits.com auth becomes obsolete and firebase takes over.

Firebase description is other here:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

They state that up to 10k phone authentifications / month will be free of charge.

Does anyone know if by single phone auth they mean an exact act of sending SMS or performing a phone call?

Can it be that simple token refresh (after 24hours) will also be considered an phone auth request?

Also, does that 10k requests also include already authenticated users or just new authetification actions that month?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this question belong to programing in any way?

Comment: its about inner workings of specific 'firebase' product for programmers, so yes, I think it belongs here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The 10K quota is for phone number verifications, not for authentication requests.

Token refresh on Firebase Authentication happens hourly. But this does not require re-verification of the phone number. The only time re-verification is needed is if your code explicitly signs the user out, or in some uncommon circumstances when the account needs to be reverified.

Comment: Frank Van Puffelen by "phone number verifications" do you mean I can only have a maximum of 10,000 and no more even after one month or its a max of 10,000 new phone number for just the one month and more can be added the following month? I am refering to the free package.

Comment: As the pricing page says, the free tier allows 10K verifications **per month**.

Comment: How many apps can be added to the project which serves free Firebase Phone Auth?